# Request Login and on success receive a callback

Tags: java, jquery, authentication, callback

I have two sites: **one** has a form, the **other one** has the database. They are on different domains.
**Site One** with the form needs the data by **Site Two**, which he only get's after a successful login.

I know how to open the login window and I know how to retrieve the data from Site Two.
But I don't get it to work, so Site One requests the login and after success Site Two sends the data.

Site Two works with  Spring and Java Server Pages, while Site One is fairly simple with pure HTML.

Here is what I have so far:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title> SomeHtml Form </title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function getParameters(){
        // get Login - **here he should wait until successful login**
        window.open('http://localhost:8080/test/login/start.mvc');

        // // USER IS LOGGING IN
        // after success, receive data
        $.getJSON('http://localhost:8080/test/secure/profile/services/export/getuser.mvc?callback=?',function(res){
            alert('Your name is '+res.lname);
            $('#lastname').val(res.lname);
            $('#firstname').val(res.fname);
        });
    }
    </script>
</head>

<body >

    <h1>Some Form</h1>

    <form action="save.html" id="FormName">
        <div>Lastname: <input type="text" id="lastname"/> </div>
        <div>Firstname: <input type="text" id="firstname"/> </div>
    </form>

    <button onclick="getParameters();">Fill Form</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope somebody can help, I am really stuck on this one!

Comment: Ok what is the issue? You see any request or response in Firebug?

Comment: With the posted code, it can't work, since I don't get any status back from "window.open(...)". I need a function, that let's me open a page, do the login and gives me a status back, although everything is happening on a different domain.
But if I call $.get(...) I can't open a login-page in the middle, because this page would be interpreted by $.get()

Comment: If iam gettin your question correctly...you can do a `window.returnValue` from the opening page to return the status back..but as this is a cross-domain call it cant be synchronous..

Comment: Your window.returnValue brought me to somewhere else nice: window.showModalDialog(), which waits, until the other window gets closed, which I can close after login!
I am trying on this now!

Comment: you have `window.close` which you can perform on success callback function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I solved the problem this way:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getParameters(){
    // login
    window.showModalDialog('http://localhost:8080/test/login/check.mvc','','dialogWidth:500px; dialogHeight:350px; resizable:no; unandorned:yes; status:no; ');
    //get data
    $.getJSON('http://localhost:8080/test/secure/profile/services/export/getuser.mvc?callback=?',function(res){
        alert('Your name is '+res.lname);
        $('#lastname').val(res.lname);
        $('#firstname').val(res.fname);
    });
}
</script>
```

The script stops working, until the ModalDialog is closed. If the user does not log in correctly in the modal dialog, the callback returns empty JSONs, and nothing gets filled out. If the user logs in correctly, the callback fetches data, it is allowed to ask for.

For the first step this works perfectly, but what if it get's a bit more complicated, for example I want to let the person choose which telephone number of the once I have in my database, he wants to get filled in the form. How could I do that?